# Notepad++ Save indents after code pasting

Tags: notepad++

When I paste a piece of code from one file to another every time I have to reindent some blocks manually because they become shifted. I understand that this happens because of different indentation of a selected block in the first file and insertion point in the second one.

For example I have this code:

```
function out(){
    function a(){
        var x=1
        x=2
    }
}
```

Then I copy only the `funtion a()` code and insert it into a new blank file. The insertion point is in the beginning of the file. So when I paste this text its first line begins from the first line of the file but other lines have indents twice of their original indents.

So the result is:

```
function a(){
        var x=1
        x=2
    }
```

And I have to select all lines except the first one and press Shift-Tab to reindent them properly.

I guess there have to be a plugin or a built-in command which inserts such pieces indenting all the lines relatively to the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I know most of N++ functions and most functions of TextFX plugin set and I can say that requested functionality is NOT among them.

Maybe the reason is that pressing **Shift+Tab** multiple times is pretty trivial.

You can make more consistent selections by selecting entire first line, including leading whitespace.

If you tend to have difficulties doing this properly, in N++ options window go to Editing section and check Display Line Numbers. With line numbers enabled, drag your mouse solely at line numbers column. This selects entire lines.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I agree it's rather better in relation to the indents but anymway I have to select all pasted contents and press Shift+TAB to align it to the insertion point. It's a bit annoying if to do it many times...

Comment: I worked in the NetBeans IDE and when I paste some multiline text it just pasts with relative indents and I have no problems with it.

Comment: So maybe I should learn how to create plugins for Notepad++ and make one for my purpose. Or I'll look for some alternatives.

Comment: @St.AngerRoman - sure, sometimes using NetBeans IDE for editing (or other IDE's) might be simply smarter. Maybe you can consider working with your files there instead of N++. Example: If I need to maintain web page by quickly editing single PHP file, I'd use N++. But if I'd need to develop something bigger at given site, I'd download PHP-oriented version of Eclipse IDE.